# Tag Challenge! June 10 to June 23: Formatting, Poetry, Ending - RESULTS

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion, contest

Welcome to stage 2 of our tag challenge! [Stage 1 was very successful](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2015/33442) so we [decided to keep going](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2016/33442), with a few slight changes.

The tags:

- [formatting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) started the challenge at 308
- [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) started at 151 questions
- [ending](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending) started at 39 questions

---

## TAGS OF THE FORTNIGHT PROMO

### Results:

It was a pretty light fortnight for entries with only NofP entering with one question on [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry). Therefore they are are clear winner, congratulations on your bragging rights. There were a few other questions that qualified but didn't bother to enter, but that's ok.

Our tags all gained questions though through re-tagging efforts;

- [formatting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) increased from 308 to 311 questions.
- [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) increased from 151 to 158 questions. (Slowly closing in on that generalist badge)
- [ending](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending) increased from 39 to 43 questions.

Not the most productive fortnight but we are slowly making progress toward the generalist badge.

### Rules:

- The contest runs for two weeks, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or more of the tags.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the challenge, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.
- Re-tagging old questions on these tags is encouraged but keep it at a reasonable rate. We don't want to flood the homepage.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use multiple tags in the same question.
- A third if you manage to tie a question in to the latest [writing exercise](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-exercise).

---

**Notes:**

- The contest started Monday?  But it's Tuesday (Wednesday for some people)!  Shush, it's the first week.
- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this challenge's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal of this challenge is:

  - Increase overall question rates toward 10 questions per day.
  - Get us to the Generalist badge by having 40 tags with over 200 questions.
  - Promote tags that may otherwise be lost or forgotten.
- Each fortnight we'll have thee tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

  - One tag will be a high popularity tag to increase participation in the challenge.
  - One tag will start the challenge between 100 and 200 questions to move us toward generalist.
  - One tag will be freely chosen by the challenge poster. Though tags from the [new tab](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) are encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

1. NofP, [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), [Revision secrets for keeping the meter and improving the beat](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45909/)